# Kaa Events not working(No listeners for event at sender)

Tags: events, kaa

The event behaves very random in my case, sometimes event works some times it does not
Looking at the debug it shows no Listeners received for the request, though I have a device added as listener for the event.

15:53:55.313 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG o.k.k.c.event.DefaultEventManager - Adding event listener resolution request. Request ID: -509992485

15:53:55.317 [pool-6-thread-2] DEBUG o.k.k.c.event.DefaultEventManager - Received event listener resolution response: [{"requestId": -509992485, "listeners": [], "result": "SUCCESS"}]

The sending code

```
kaaClient.attachUser("R0006", kaaClient.getEndpointAccessToken(), new UserAttachCallback() {
    public void onAttachResult(UserAttachResponse response) {
        LOG.debug("Attach Status - " + response.getResult());
        while (true) {
            LOG.info("Sending Event...");
              List<String> FQNs = new LinkedList<String>();
FQNs.add(ScanEventFamily.class.getName());

kaaClient.findEventListeners(FQNs, new FindEventListenersCallback() {
    public void onEventListenersReceived(List<String> eventListeners) {
      for(int i = 0; i< eventListeners.size(); i++) {
          LOG.info("Listeners - " + eventListeners.get(i));
          kaaClient.getEventFamilyFactory().getScanEventFamily().sendEvent(new ScanInfo() {{
              setTransactionId("123");
              setEquipmentId("1234");
              setEvent("ENTRY");
              setScanTime(1234569L);
              setSourceId("5");
              setDestinationId("10");
          }}, eventListeners.get(i));
      }
    }
    public void onRequestFailed() {
        LOG.info("Listeners Request Failed");
    }
})
```

The Listeners code

```
kaaClient.attachUser( "R0005", kaaClient.getEndpointAccessToken(), new UserAttachCallback() {
     public void onAttachResult(UserAttachResponse response) {
         LOG.debug  ("Attach Status - " + response.getResult());
         ScanEventFamily   scanEventFamily = kaaClient.getEventFamilyFactory().getScanEventFamily();
         ScanEventFamily.Listener listener = (event, source) -> {
             LOG.info("Event Received - " + event);
         };
         scanEventFamily.addListener(listener);
     }
});
```

What could be the cause of this.
Let me know if any addition information is required.

Regards,
Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some problem with configuration on Kaa server, not on client. Please use [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Events/) page about events for more information.